# curl tests automatization?

Tags: automated-testing, http

We have a list(s) of URLs, the task is to test all the URLs:

- they should return proper response code which is configured somehow it the list
- some should return content having a specified keyword in it
- some should be checked considering redirects, some not.
- they should be fast enough to fit in a defined timeframe
- etc

**The question:** is there any ready-to-use tool that allows just to pass the properly formatted list of URLs as input and get the pass/fail answer?

The first tool I can think about to do the job is a wrapper around `curl`, however, we would need to write a script to parse list/parameters (expected response code, optional keyword, whether to follow redirects, etc). I can write it on my own but I'm new in testing so there definitely is something I haven't thought of about yet but which might be in that tool already.

No GUI/rendering analyze required, the process will be run in CI/CD pipeline i.e. in fully detached/automated mode without access to any graphical interface. Linux.

Comment: What about Postman?

Comment: curl, postman with newman, python with request library, ... You choose. In my experience, curl is not very comfortable to use, but it could be done.

Comment: @MateMrše Postman itself afaik cannot run headless, this is why I didn't consider it. So the answer would be Postman+newman, if my understanding is correct. If you post it, I'll accept it.

Comment: @putnik who told you cannot run postman without UI ,Newman is a command line utility to run postman scripts . You dont need postman installed in the target system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman has a command line Collection Runer called [Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/):

> By default, Newman exits with a status code of 0 if everything runs as expected with no exceptions. You can configure your continuous integration tools to respond to Newman's exit codes and correspondingly pass or fail a build.

You can easily integrate it with

- [Jenkins](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/integration-with-jenkins/)
- [Travis CI](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/integration-with-travis/)
- [Docker](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/newman-with-docker/)

Answer (score 1):

If you go the bash route The following may help.

It uses a function called `do_test` that let you pass a function and test the results.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. colors_for_text.sh 2> /dev/null

do_test () {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - do_test: No parameters provided - Usage is do_test [function_name] \$LINENO [expected result] [optional params]\n"
    exit 1
  elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - do_test: Two parameters missing - \$LINENO and expected result (other params as needed)\n"
    exit 1
  fi
  declare -ig test_runs test_passes test_fails
  local -r function="$1";shift
  local -r line_number="$1";shift
  local failfast="False"
  local debug="False"
  local verbose="False"
  local test_description=
  local test_matcher=
  local expected=
  local pass_on_params=
  local command_not_found=False
  type "setup" &> /dev/null && setup
  # TODO Replace with for loop (initial attempts failed)
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "debug" ]] && debug="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "verbose" ]] && verbose="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "debug" ]] && debug="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^description= ]]; then
    [[ `echo $1 | grep =` ]] && test_description=`echo $1 | sed 's/.*=//'`' ' &&
    shift
  fi
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^matcher= ]]; then
    [[ `echo "$1" | grep =` ]] && test_matcher="`echo "$1" | sed 's/matcher=//'`" &&
    shift
  fi
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - Function: $function, Line: $line_number \n
do_test: Third parameter missing - expected result\n"
    exit 1
  fi
  expected="$1";shift
  pass_on_params="$@"
  $function ${pass_on_params[@]} 2> $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt"
  cat $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt" | grep -i "command not found" &&
    command_not_found=True
  debug_printf "(debug)"
  if [[ $command_not_found == "True" ]]; then
    record_script_failure "$function"
  elif [[ "$test_matcher" == "==" ]]; then
    [[ "$result" == $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  elif [[ "$expected" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    [[ "$result" -eq $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  else
    [[ "$result" == $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  fi
  test_runs+=1
}
record_test_success () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  printf "$pass_color"."$color_end"
  [[ "$verbose" == "True" ]] && printf "$function"
  test_passes+=1
}
record_test_failure () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  test_fails+=1
  printf "$fail_color"F"$color_end"
  function_exists? "$function" &&
    error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""$test_description""Line: $line_number - \
'$function ${pass_on_params[@]}' failed:\n\
Expected: $expected\n\
Received: $result $color_end\n\n" ||
    error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""Line: $line_number: \
Function '$function' is undefined\n"
  [[ "$failfast" == "True" ]] && failfast "Test" $error_messages
}
record_script_failure () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  test_fails+=1
  err=`cat $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt"`
  printf $err
  error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""Line: $line_number: \
Error within function '$function', getting \"command not found\" in $err \n"
  [[ "$failfast" == "True" ]] && failfast "Script" $error_messages
}
failfast () {
  printf "\n$1 error & failfast set to exit immediately.\n$2\n" && exit 1
}

no_param_quit () {
  printf "\nError - 1 parameter required for: $1 - exiting\n" && exit 1
}
function_exists?() {
    declare -f -F $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}
debug_echo () {
  [[ "$debug" == "True" ]] && echo "$1"
}
debug_printf () {
  [[ "$debug" == "True" ]] && printf "$1"
}
13:11:33 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/sh__sed__awk/euler 
$
```

For usage see the bottom of https://durrantm.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/tdd-for-sh/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answers,

in postman if you click the collection and click view in web you can see the equavalent curl commands:

[image]

**Then you can see curl comment in the api documentation :**

[image]

**Postman also supports retrieving code snippets in different programming languages:**

Click the specific request and then click code:

[image]

Then you can see code as below , you can select which programming language you wnat the code generated for from the list :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) for manual testing.

I have previously used [Soap UI](https://www.soapui.org/) as well and automated this more.